# How to pay customers from sales made through my platform?

Tags: paypal, stripe-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

not sure if this is the correct place to ask this but. I am building a jb tweak which once done will be released to the public. This tweak will have a payment option for paid features.

Tweak will be customized to be able to add features and pay the respected devs.

I want to be able to charge a commission from whatever sales they make through my public tweak.

For example if they sell their premium for $9.99 then i would get lets say a 10% commission which would go to my business account.

As of now i have it working to be sent to my paypal business account. Which works great but if i plan to releasing this to the public all purchases will end up in my account which i dont want. I only want whatever commission percentage i put.

I was thinking something along the lines of maybe run all checkouts through my business account, substract the commission and send remaining balance to whatever developer made the sale. The problem is that payouts api has to be approved and paypal denied due to being “high risk”.

My question is, how would i be able to charge commission per sales from devs using my platform?

I looked into stripe but i am not sure if their api can do this.

Tried to apply for paypal payouts api but that didnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe supports flows like your with their [Connect product](https://stripe.com/docs/connect). You can read more about the different connect account types [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts) but based on what you're describing, you'll likely want to look into using [Express](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/express-accounts) or [Custom](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/custom-accounts) connect accounts (for the developers making the sales). For payments you'll either want to use [Destination charges](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges) (payments are made on your own account and some portion is automatically transferred to a connect account) or [Separate Charges and Transfers](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/charges-transfers) (payments are made on your own platform account and you make separate API calls to transfer funds to one or more connect accounts).